# Need help to refactor FIrebase phone authentication into MVVM architecture

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-mvvm

I am unable to figure out how to handle login Result from FirebaseLoginRepository class back to LoginViewModel after authentication like whether it's successful or not ,should i use a callback listener as we do in MVP pattern ?

Pardon me in case of misunderstanding or some unconventional issue as this is my first question on StackOverflow

I don't know i don't have the slightest idea and couldn't find anything useful over the internet

```
public void login{

        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //using login Result callback as unable to figure out how 
                    //to hand back result to LoginViewModel 
                   //i am certain that doing this breaks the principle of MVVM
                    loginResultCallback.onSuccess();
                }else {
                    loginResultCallback.onError();
                }
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is because the firebase API requires a callback & you are unsure how to get the result from this callback into your LiveData object?

Comment: Yeah exactly the same thing ,sorry couldn't explain it better as I am new to the stuff so learning and working my way around it

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this on a background thread, you could do something like:

```
public void login{
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //using login Result callback as unable to figure out how 
                    //to hand back result to LoginViewModel 
                   //i am certain that doing this breaks the principle of MVVM
                   viewModel.something = something;
                }else {
                    loginResultCallback.onError();
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
          latch.await(30000);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
          Log.e("TUT", "Error timeed out", e);
        }
}
```

This allows you to block a thread and wait for a callback to happen, thus its a way to abstract a callback and use LiveData. You just have to be aware of what it is doing to the threads.

Outside of this you should look to see if the firebase API has a synchronous method for the same API.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: i didn't quite understand how would that help my case as i wanted my login class to be independent of everything i were just asking for a better way to return the login result,but thanks a lot for getting back to me

Comment: this changes your login method to synchronously return the login result to your livedata object.

Comment: I did understand that but isn't it still tightly coupled? Pardon me as I am new to the concept of clean code and decoupling still learning

Comment: mm not really enough code for me to comment on coupling sorry